# Multiple File Upload in Grails

Tags: jquery, grails, file-upload

I'm trying to integrate the excellent [jquery-file-upload from blueimp](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) into Grails 2.0 and to write a new plugin for that. I know there is [already a plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/jquery-file-upload), but it doesn't use resources and it hasn't been updated for 9 months, and jquery-file-upload has changed a lot in that time.

So I put all of the files of the distribution in my plugin, and now I'm trying to write a controller action that can handle the upload. The problem is that `request.getFileNames()` only gives me one `files[]` entry and I don't know how to retrieve the 3 individual files I am uploading.

How do you handle the files sent by an input like this: `<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>`?

Answer (score 4):

Actually I figured it out. There is only one `input[type=file]` in the form and if I select several files they are not sent on the same request. The `query-file-upload` script sends as many POST requests as there are files. That's why `request.getFileNames()` only gives me one entry each time. I managed to create my plugin, it will be published soon. Watch out for http://grails.org/plugin/bootstrap-file-upload.

Answer (score 2):

`request.getFileNames` returns an array - you can iterate over this array to obtain all the files. The example is already there on the plugin description.

```
def all = request.getFileNames()
all.each {name ->
   def file = request.getFile(name)
}
```

This should give you all the files that were uploaded.