# Multiple file input type upload in grails

Tags: html, grails, file-upload, upload

When I use the 'multiple' attribute I can't get it to work:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
```

The controller action method body:

```
request.getFileNames().each {
    println it
}
```

The problem is that this iteration returns only one file. Can anyone help me to obtain all the files uploaded? (I'm using grails 2.0.3)

Comment: Looks like similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155645/multiple-file-upload-in-grails)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to get at the multiple file part of the request.

I think you can do

```
request.getMultiFileMap()
```

or

```
request.multiFileMap.documentFile
```

Comment: How is this working? I am getting exception that those methods do not exist.

Comment: I had to add   if(request  instanceof MultipartHttpServletRequest){} on my controller

Answer (score 4):

Grails 2 uses Spring 3 which uses the [MultipartRequest](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartRequest.html) class to handle this.

This class has a getFiles(String name) function which you can use in your case. So this will result in the following code:

```
request.getFiles("files[]").each { file ->
    log.debug(file.originalFilename)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this

```
request.multiFileMap.get("files[]")
```