# Upload Image to the DB

Tags: grails, file-upload

I'm trying to upload an image to the DB but when I try to see what is in the `params`, I find in `fileupload` is the image's name something like  `org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile@eeed792`. For example `params [fileupload:android-logo.jpg]`.

Here is the domain class:

```
class Photos {
Date dateCreated
byte [] photo
Date lastUpdated

static constraints = {

}
static mapping ={ photo(sqlType:"BLOB") }
}
```

the GSP :

```
 <label>Photos:</label>
            <input class="inputFiles" type="file" name="fileupload" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
```

What may be causing this ?

Comment: sounds like it is going to be a huge database. Why not store a reference to the file i.e. Sha string of it and store the file on filesystem - nightmare DB management / backup / restore..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File uploads don't get directly injected into params.  You have to use request.getFile('paramname')

Take a look at this: http://www.slideshare.net/cavneb/upload-files-with-grails

Comment: after adding `enctype='multipart/form-data'` to the `form` solved the problem , but how to handle the `org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile` when adding `multiple="multiple"` to the uploading field to upload multiple images  .

Comment: Another search yields: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425891/multiple-file-input-type-upload-in-grails, or there's a plugin https://grails.org/plugin/uploadr