# How to read the content of a file with CommonsMultipartFile in Grails

Tags: grails, file-upload

I can't read the file that I upload in Grails. `write` is the column in the db where I store the file that I uploaded.

```
CommonsMultipartFile testFile = request.getFile('templateFile')
InputStream inputStream = testFile.getInputStream()
bookInstance.write = inputStream
```

Comment: What type is the `write` property of `bookInstance`?

Comment: The type is a String

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's many ways you can do it. Have a look:

[uploading a file in grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439135/uploading-a-file-in-grails)

[how to upload file into server directory with grails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519144/how-to-upload-file-into-server-directory-with-grails)

[Multiple File Upload in Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155645/multiple-file-upload-in-grails?rq=1)

and much more!

If you want the content of the file as a string you can do:

```
CommonsMultipartFile testFile = request.getFile('templateFile')
InputStream inputStream = testFile.getInputStream()
bookInstance.write = inputStream?.text
```

Notice the calling of `getText()` on the stream instance.

Comment: Look the error message with your suggestion: No such property: write for class:  Possible solutions: dirty

Comment: Just assign the String to a field you've created on the bookInstance class.

Answer (score 0):

Probabily you forgot to use a multipart encoded form: `<form enctype="multipart/form-data">`. In Grails, you can use a `<g:uploadForm>`. Could you check that in your gsp/html code?